# SQL Developer Connection

Tags: sql, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a database in SQL Developer so I can start practising SQL. Which db should I create a connection with to begin is it 10g express?

I have tried creating a new connection; however, I have not been successful. I keep getting the error message:

"Status : Failure-Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

I am really lost, all the tutorials I can find seem to move through the new connection process effortlessly without any connection error help; most of the information seems to be more advanced than the basic setup help I need.

Thanks.

PS. any good beginner resources for learning SQL would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the URL you are using to connect to OracleXE?

Comment: It depends very much on what databases you have installed...  It sounds like you're looking at Oracle, would that be right?

Comment: I can't seem to get any connection details, as the connection is never established. I have downloaded oracle SQL developer and OracleXE

Answer (score 0):

http://connectionstrings.com

And the oracle page there:

http://connectionstrings.com/oracle

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Oracle has any online development database that you can connect to, so it seems like your best bet is to run express edition locally and use some of the sample schemas.  More info here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/getting-started-155046.html

Comment: So, starting out I should play around with SQL in the SQL commands section by logging into 10g express edition from the DB homepage? There is no way to practice in SQL Developer?